# AWS CDK Pipelines - Failing To Source Repository Automatically

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

**Problem:** The sourcing stage cannot source `EVENTS` of the repository, and thus the code pipeline is not being initiated upon `git push`.

**Expected Behaviour:** When new code is sent to the repository's "dev" branch, it triggers the code pipeline.

[image: AWS Code Commit Source Stage]

**CDK Code:**

```
this.codePipeline.addStage({
  stageName: "Source",
  actions: [
    new CodeCommitSourceAction({
      actionName: 'Source',
      repository: this.codeRepository,
      branch: context.branchName,
      codeBuildCloneOutput: true,
      runOrder: 1,
      output: sourceOutput,
      trigger: CodeCommitTrigger.EVENTS,
    })
  ]
});
```

**Useful Links:**

1. [CodeCommitTrigger.EVENTS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitTrigger.html#events)
2. [CodeCommitSourceAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction.html)

***Note:** Clicking "Release Change" works successfully as a manual trigger for initiating the pipeline.*

Comment: My thoughts are `context.branchName` cannot be accessed at the source stage.

Comment: What is the value of `context.branchName`?

Comment: Great question by the way. This is has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This was due `branchName` being `undefined`. Thus, it looked for the master branch, which is the default behavior.

Comment: But the question says that there were zero changes to the source stage - did this work at some point? What is `context` here? Where is that variable defined?

Comment: That's a great point. I must have been wrong. I'll look to change the question now.

Comment: Can you clarify what the `context` variable is here and what you mean by `the CDK pipelines does not, at the time of sourcing the repository, know what the context is`. If you're talking about CDK context - then it does know it, but that's now how you access the context values.

Comment: This answer is not correct as written - CDK pipeline does in fact know the context. If it doesn't, that mean you misconfigured something.